# toliet fill valve squirts a little water every 30 seconds

Tags: toilet

Toilet fill valve (vertical float) one squirt of water every 30 seconds after the bowl is filled. I replaced the fill valve and the new one does the same thing. Also replaced the flapper no other issue flushes just fine and fills just fine to the water line. More annoying than anything else. What could cause this. Thanks

Comment: Usually this happens when water is leaking from the tank and the water level drops. Corrosion around the shutoff valve can also cause it. Since you replaced the fill valve and the flapper I would try setting the float valve to shut off earlier (lower water level) and see if that helps.

Comment: You replaced the flapper, good.  Did you check the seat the flapper rests on to make sure there's no debris  preventing a good seal?  sometimes they can get chipped.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions. I did clean the debris on the seat. Still the same. I found out that the tube coming off the fill valve that hangs on and in the refill tube needs to be above the water level. In other words the rubber hose off of the fill valve was below the water level on both the old and new fill valve. So had I lowered the float valve down below the tube it would have solved the problem. Anyway got a  new fill valve, new flapper and learned something in the process. Thanks again.

Comment: The rubber tube should not be loose in the tank. It goes into the refill tube (overfill tube) to rinse it. See https://www.fluidmaster.com/toilet-problems/identifying-parts-toilet-tank/